# How to keep nested router views visible under a modal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, modal-dialog, vue-router, nested-views

I have a problem on a Vue3 app.

I have a `mainRouterView` and a `modalRouterView` inside `App.vue`.
`mainRouterView` displays various stuff, including a child `bottomRouterView`, which displays all the main pages (Home, Page A, Page B, etc.).

I need to display modals above everything, inside `modalRouterView`, without hiding what's under. Modals can be triggered from any page.

**Problem**
When I open modals they show up correctly, `mainRouterView` and `bottomRouterView` are still here. But the content inside `bottomRouterView` disappears. Which means `Home`, `Page A`, `Page B`, etc.. aren't displayed anymore.

**Question**
How can I fix my code so that the `bottomRouterView` still displays its content (`Home`, `Page A`, `Page B`, etc.)? I think the problem comes from the line `default: Main` for the `/modal` route in my router, as in it's not specific enough.

**Structure**

```
App.vue/
├── modalRouterView/
│   ├── Modal A
│   ├── Modal B
│   └── ...
└── mainRouterView/
    └── bottomRouterView/
        ├── Home
        ├── Page A
        ├── Page B
        └── ...
```

**Router**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Main,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        components: {
          bottomRouterView: Home,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'page-a',
        components: {
          bottomRouterView: PageA,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'page-b',
        components: {
          bottomRouterView: PageB,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/modal',
    components: {
      default: Main,
      modalRouterView: Modal,
    },
    props: true,
    meta: {
      showModal: true
    }
  },
];
```

**Modal**

```
<div v-if="showModal" class="modal-route">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <router-view name="modalRouterView"></router-view>
  </div>
</div>
```

**mainRouterView** which doesn't really have a name, I named it on my post so that it's more understandable

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem

I've given a name to the router in App.vue (don't think it changed anything, but it's clearer)

```
<router-view name="mainRouterView"></router-view>
```

And I've edited the router. I've moved the modal part as a child of root, and I've added a beforeEnter() to conditionally assign a component to bottomRouterView depending on the view we're coming from.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    components: {
      mainRouterView: Main,
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'home'
        components: {
          bottomRouterView: Home,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'page-a',
        name: 'page-a'
        components: {
          bottomRouterView: PageA,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'page-b',
        name: 'page-b'
        components: {
          bottomRouterView: PageB,
        },
      },
      {
        path: 'modal',
        name: 'modal',
        components: {
          mainRouterView: Main,
          bottomRouterView: null,
          modalRouterView: Modal,
        },
        props: true,
        meta: {
          showModal: true
        },
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
          const previousRoute = from.name;
          let componentForBottomRouterView;

          switch (previousRoute) {
            case 'home':
              componentForBottomRouterView = Home;
              break;
            case 'page-a':
              componentForBottomRouterView = PageA;
              break;
            case 'page-b':
              componentForBottomRouterView = PageB;
              break;
            default:
              componentForBottomRouterView = Home;
          }
          const bottomRouterViewRoute = to.matched.find(route => route.name === 'modal');
          if (bottomRouterViewRoute) {
            bottomRouterViewRoute.components.bottomRouterView = componentForBottomRouterView;
          }

          next();
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```